# Vue3 vite : npm run serve doesn't load all my files (result: 404)

Tags: vue.js

I'm using npm run serve to test my app in dev (it's a vite template). Lately I ran into 404 problems. The whole 'services' directory is missing in dev mode and I get a 404 error. `import SongService from '@/services/SongService'` fails.
But: `import SongService from '../services/SongService'` is OK.

Why is my app failing to load the assets? Here's the structure of my project:

```
- src
 - router
  index.js
 - services
  Api.js
  SongService.js
 - views
 App.vue
 main.js
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vite": "^1.0.0-rc.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `package.json` file?

Comment: I can : what do you think?